# In k&r book exercise 1.18 write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input,and to delete entirely blank lines

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1024

int getline(char s[], int lim);

main()
{
    int i, len;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        i = len - 2;
        while (i >= 0 && (line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t'))
            --i;
        if (i >= 0) {
            line[i+1] = '\n';
            line[i+2] = '\0';
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
  int i,c;

  for(i=0;i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';++i)
    s[i] = c;
  if( c == '\n')
  {
    s[i]=c;
    ++i;
  }
  s[i]='\0';

  return i;
}
```

This is my program which i tired but it seems like displaying the same input without any changes.I can't able to understand what mistake i did ....
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly did you verify that the trailing spaces haven't been removed?

Comment: Could you shoot the expected output and the output you are getting?

Comment: input - Hi how   are u ? output- Hi how   are u ? its same like this without any changes

Comment: BTW, K&R was written before POSIX specifications reserved the name `getline`; if you're on a POSIX system you should name that function something else

Answer (score 1):

Your `getline` function increments `i` (the length returned) for the `'\n'`, but not for the terminating `'\0'`.

Hence, in `i = len - 2;` you should be subtracting one, not two... right? To clarify, **I'm suggesting that you try `i = len - 1;`**!

Comment: ya i tired i=len-2 bt still no changes in output it does not removes the blanks and tabs

Comment: @sharmilanarayanan You missed the point. I've edited and bolded it for your benefit.

Comment: oops!! sry i tired i=len-1 only bt there is no changes in output

Comment: @sharmilanarayanan Then your testcase isn't comprehensive enough to pick up the difference. Did you test lines that contain only one trailing whitespace character?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of hopefully helpful hints.

- There is already a function `getline()`, you are overruling that name. If you increase your compilation warning level then you'll probably see the warning. Anyway, assuming you want to have your own line-reading function, you could change it to say `my_getline()`. If you do this, then your program works for me.
- Similarly, your declaration of `main()` doesn't have the type in front of it as in `int main()`. That's OK, the default type is `int`, but for neatness' sake, you should put the type in there (again, to avoid compilation warnings when you increase the warning level).
- Your program can't handle lines longer than 1024 characters. That's ok if you can live with this limitation. If you would want to get rid of this limitation, then you'd want to wire `my_getline()` in such a way that it would return a pointer to allocated memory holding the entire line of text that it read. In `main()` you could strip your trailing space etc. and then `free()` the memory. In this case the prototype of `my_getline()` would be of course `char *my_getline()`.

Comment: Note: when K&R was written, `getline()` was not a function.  It's been added to `<stdio.h>` in the intervening decades.

Comment: Similarly, in the days of K&R C (and C89), `main` wasn't required to explicitly return `int`... and the last point seems to miss the point of the exercise. which is to reinforce string handling, not dynamic storage duration. The book hasn't yet mentioned `malloc` at that point...

Comment: Detail: `getline()` is not in the C spec nor is it a reserved name.  It is common in *nix.  Good enough reason to avoid that name.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the number of characters after removing white-space characters(blanks , tabs ) then compare with no of characters before removing the white-spaces . if they differ your program works..

you will not be able to see the difference in our input and out since we are dealing with white space characters here..

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me. Please note that I have not defined any new functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
#define INLINE 1
#define OUTLINE 0

int main(void) {
    int i = 0, j, c;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int status = OUTLINE;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\n') {
            line[i] = c;
            i++;
        } else if (c == '\n'){
            line[i] = '\n';
            line[i+1] = '\0';
            for (j = i; j >= 0 && status == OUTLINE; j--) {
                char lc = line[j];
                if (lc == ' ' || lc == '\t') {
                    line[j] = '\n';
                    line[j+1] = '\0';
                    status = INLINE;
                }
            }
            printf("%s", line);
            for (j = 0; j < MAXLINE; j++) {
                line[j] = 0;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit this answer to explain why this solution works and ideally how it addresses the problems in the code in the original question?